# Sax Parser Missing opening Element

Tags: java, xml, sax

Im having an issue opening the stackoverflow posts XML dump using the java sax parser. It recognizes the end of each element but seems to skip the startElement method. Im using the example code:

```
 try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName) throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse(filename, handler);
```

The XML is structured simply as a row with a number of attributes:

```
<row Id="29621" "postTypeID=1" AcceptedAnswer...>
```

and the output from the code above is simply:

```
End Element :row
```

I have tried adding @Override annotations to the methods inside the defaultHandler however it throws an error if i try to override the startElement. Can anyone recommend how to correct this issue and why startElement cannot be overriden?

Comment: Which error do you get when overriding ? And are you using `org.xml.sax.Attributes` and `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` classes  in your code ?

Comment: ok actually i was half way through mentioning that i had no error and your second recommendation was correct the wrong library had been imported. It now functions, if u want to post it as an answer ill mark it as correct :) thanks so much!

Comment: As it is more like a typo, posting an answer wouldn't really help other persons, but I'm glad that it fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error when adding an `Override` annotation, the most likely explanation is that the signature of your method does not quite match the one of the method you intend to override.

From the [Java 8 JavaDocs of the SAX DefaultParser:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html)

```
public void startElement(String uri,
                     String localName,
                     String qName,
                     Attributes attributes)
              throws SAXException
```

this looks ok, but possibly you are using a different version.